# Implementing model (autoencoder + CNN) how to ensure my model is not overfitting?

Tags: python, autoencoder, roc, conv-neural-network, k-fold

I am using the Kfold method. I have a dataset of size 1035. I want to ensure that my model is not overfitting since I am getting the test accuracy of 100% and if I increase the epoch it reaches 100% test accuracy and then goes back to 77%. I have also implemented early stopping but the patience level which I have set it's not able to reach there since every iteration it is learning and patience number is reset.
Can someone suggest me what can I do? Is there something wrong with my model?
I tried changing the learning rate but it affects my ROC curve but I am getting 100% test accuracy.

```
class convnet(nn.Module):
def __init__(self,num_inputs=9950,num_latent=200):
    super(convnet,self).__init__()
    
    self.num_inputs=num_inputs                
    
    
    self.fc_encoder= nn.Sequential( 
        nn.Linear(num_inputs,4975)
    )
    self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(4975,num_inputs)
    )
    self.con1=nn.Conv1d(1, 2, 5)
    self.max1=nn.MaxPool1d(4)
    self.con2=nn.Conv1d(2, 4, 5)
    self.max2=nn.MaxPool1d(4)
    self.l1=nn.Linear(2480,1024)
    self.drop=nn.Dropout(p= 0.5)
    self.l2=nn.Linear(1024,512)
    self.l3=nn.Linear(512,128)
    self.l4=nn.Linear(128,32)
    self.l5=nn.Linear(32,1)   
    
def forward(self, x):
    
    # print(x.shape)
    x = self.fc_encoder(x)
    # print("After Encoder",x.shape)
    x = self.decoder(x)

    # print("After Decoder",x.shape)
    x=x.unsqueeze(1)
    # print("After Decoder and Unsequeeze",x.shape)
    x=self.con1(x)
    x=self.max1(x)
    x=self.con2(x)
    x=self.max2(x)
    x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
    x=self.l1(x)
    x=self.drop(x)
    x=self.l2(x)
    x=self.l3(x)
    x=self.l4(x)
    x=self.l5(x)


    # print("After CNN",x.shape)
    
    return torch.sigmoid(x)
```

Comment: There's a lot of stuff for just `overfitting`. Try dropout, decreasing the bottleneck size, data augmentation.

Comment: I tried dropout does not help.

Comment: How did you try dropout? and where (if you're using it as a layer or on a layer)? And what was your dropout rate?

Comment: I am adding my model in the question I asked. Please look at the question again.

Comment: You can try more than one dropout layer

Comment: Also I'm not used to torch syntax yet but it seems like you only have a single activation layer – five consecutive linear layers is equivalent to having 1 – a series of matrix multiplications can be represented with a single matrix. Having that many linear layers does not improve your network, consider less layers with activations in between

Comment: I will apply whatever you said thank you so much for your help

Comment: Hey @MZ, I did what you said to add but there is no improvement instead I am getting accuracy of 100% for all the kfold. Can u suggest me something else to improve?

Comment: how much did you decrease your bottleneck size by?

Comment: it's already 4975 from 9475. I didn't reduce that